# What does "search" word/command in JS mean?

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I'm reading about Web Workers http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/workers.html#a-background-number-crunching-worker.

There is a code example with a word "search". What does it mean? Is it a new command?

```
var n = 1;
search: while (true) {
  n += 1;
  for (var i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(n); i += 1)
    if (n % i == 0)
     continue search;
  // found a prime!
  postMessage(n);
}
```

Comment: It's just a label, could also be called bacon. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label

Comment: Useful if you have say 2 nested loops and you need to break out of the outer loop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is *labelled continue*. The `while` loop has `search:` label, and `continue` will continue the while loop. Without the label it would continue the `for` loop.